# Bluebird Promises.map .then() : not working

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I'm using bluebird Promise.map for concurrent downloads

this is the download function

```
async function concuDownload2(nultUrls) {

      Promise.map(nultUrls, nult => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          console.log('Downloading Image: ' + nult.file_name);
          let jpath = path.join(dir, nult.file_name);
          request(nult.url).on('error', reject).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(jpath)).on('finish', () => {
              console.log('Downloaded Image: ' + nult.file_name);
              resolve();
          });
      }), {
          concurrency: 100
      }).then(() => {
          console.log('All Image Downloaded!');
      }).catch(err => {
          console.error('Failed: ' + err.message);
      });
 }
```

**updated Code:**

```
function concuDownload2(nultUrls) {    

       Promise.map(nultUrls, nult => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {           

            let jpath = path.join(dir, nult.file_name);        

            (nult.url.substr(0, 5) === 'https' ? https : http).get(nult.url, (res) => {             
                if (res.statusCode == 200) {


                    res.setEncoding('binary');
                    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                        chunks += chunk;

                    }).on('end', () => {
                        var stream = fs.createWriteStream(jpath);
                        stream.write(chunks, 'binary');
                        stream.on('finish', () => {
                            console.log(nult.file_name + ' Saved !')
                            resolve('File Saved !');
                        });
                        stream.on('error', (err) => {
                            console.log('File Error:', err)
                              reject(err)
                        });
                        res.pipe(stream);
                    })

                }
                else  {
                   console.log('File couldn\'t be retrieved', nult.url);           

                }

            }).on('error', (e) => {
                console.log("Error:" + nult.url + e);

            });

        }), {
            concurrency: 100
        }).then(() => {
              console.log('All Image Downloaded!');

        }).catch(err => {
            console.error('Failed-end: ' + err);

        });
    }
```

After all the images are downloaded, I'm not getting message 'All Messages Downloaded';

**Update:** I've updated the function. This error occurs only when a request returns error

Comment: Are you getting a reject?  If any promise in the array is rejected the whole map gets rejected

Comment: Maybe the write stream emits an error? You only listen for errors on the request stream.

Comment: Btw, there's no reason to make `concuDownload2` an `async` function, since you don't use the `await` keyword anywhere.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. The error occurs only when one of the request fails. When all the links are successfully requested, .then() works

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Working Example using **Promise.all**

```
    var nultUrls = [
      {
        "file_name": "Bluebonnet Field Ellis County Texas.jpg",
        "url": "https://i.redd.it/gn02mp7w99841.jpg",
        "downloadId": "6r4a84k4wpgry6"
      },
      {
        "file_name": "Shot this on my way home from work this morning The sun rises on a new decade Happy New Year!.jpg",
        "url": "https://i.redd.it/i0n394rv99841.jpg",
        "downloadId": "6r4a84k4wpgry7"
      },
      {
        "file_name": "The big Lego llama statue I made (link in comments) left a weird print on this cushioned seat It looks like there is Lego inside the cushion part.jpg",
        "url": "https://i.redd.it/in2qc4vr99841.jpg",
        "downloadId": "6r4a84k4wpgry8"
      },
      {
        "file_name": "Buoys are bigger than youd think.jpg",
        "url": "https://i.redd.it/r26olhzt99841.jpg",
        "downloadId": "6r4a84k4wpgry9"
      }];


          function concuDownload2(nultUrls) {

          Promise.all(nultUrls.map(nult => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              console.log('Downloading Image: ' + nult.file_name);
             resolve();
// Code commented for testing
             // let jpath = path.join(dir, nult.file_name);
            //  request(nult.url).on('error', reject).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(jpath)).on('finish', () => {
             //     console.log('Downloaded Image: ' + nult.file_name);
            //      resolve();
          //    })
          }), {
              concurrency: 100
          })).then(() => {
              console.log('All Image Downloaded!');
          }).catch(err => {
              console.error('Failed: ' + err.message);
          });
     }

     concuDownload2(nultUrls)
```

you can Check by pasting the above code in the link below

https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-nodejs-online/

Reference:
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

Comment: Please check my updated answer. The error occurs only when one of the request fails. When all the links are successfully requested, .then() works